# sublimeTest3 Package install can't find SideBarEnhancements插件

Tags: sublimetext3, package-control

I know it can be found on GitHub. I just want to know why it can't be found on Package Control. I know it can be downloaded from GitHub. I want to know what is causing this problem.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRA6t.png)

Comment: This is an English language website. Please only use English in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It has been currently removed from PackageControl for unknown reasons.

Update: See [this thread](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements/issues/332) for more details.

Second update: The author has disabled issues on the repository and added installation instructions in the README.